# How to export SQL Server table data into text file as Insert command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table with bulk data (say 2 Million rows). I need to export this data into a text file.

I've approached Generate Scripts method by which it throws

> System.OutOfMemoryExeception.

I need to some how convert the data into text file. Can `sqlcmd` approach be helpful? If so please suggest the steps.

Comment: Might help to show an example of your data and the needed output (CSV, XML, fixed width, ...)

Comment: Please use **internationally understood** mesaurement - thousands, millions, billions etc.

Comment: @marc_s - **20 lakh = 2 Million**

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `xp_cmdshell` in `Facets` and run this -

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM sys.schemas" queryout "D:\sample.txt" -S ' + @@servername + ' -T -w -r -t'
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @sql
```